# Postman aways identify 200 on Nodejs + Express even when i send other

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

I'm using API coded in NodeJS but always Postman identify HttpStatus 200, even when i send 4XX or other.

I'm using express and body-parser

As you can see below:
[image]

The code is:

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
    try{
            let dados = await busca(0);
            let pasta = '/upload/'
            let nomearquivo = '';

            var contents = '';

            if (dados){
                    for (const [idx,row] of dados.entries()){
                            nomearquivo = pasta + row.arquivotitulo;

                            if (fs.existsSync(nomearquivo)){
                                    contents = fs.readFileSync(nomearquivo, {encoding:'base64'});
                                    dados[idx]['arquivotitulo64'] = contents;
                            }
                    }
                    return res.status(200).send(dados);
            }else{
                    return res.sendStatus(404);
            }

    }catch (err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
```

});

Can anyone help me to send correctly resposes that turns possible to identify in Postman the correct Status code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this `res.status(404).send('Not Found');` It should work and straightforwrd

Comment: I think the message with the status did the difference. Works Fine!!! Thank you

Comment: Some cases didn't work fine. I think it's because i'm on async function